# Log file in Topbeat

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and Topbeat tools.

When I start the topbeat service and look through my browser by typing **`localhost:9200/topbeat-*/_search?pretty`**, I get data about my system.

But I want to know where the complete information file is being stored.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The topbeat data is stored in Elasticsearch. The location of Elasticsearch' files is documented here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-dir-layout.html 
If you want to backup the data the normal way is with the builtin tools: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html. There are also other ones out there like taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump on github.